# Trouble with mediaelement.js and Phonegap

Tags: cordova, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I am working on building an android HTML5 music player, i am using mediaelement.js as my plugin. The player works perfect on my Chrome browser. However when i compile with phonegap, my music player doesn't work. Has someone else experienced this issue, and what's the solution

Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is mediaelement.js? Is it set up as a Cordova plugin or just a piece of JavaScript? Can you provide the code for the page, the logs you are seeing, and possibly your config.xml? What devices have you tested on?

Comment: @MBillau Its a problem with phonegap, i am testing on my mobile device so i can't really see the output. Is there anyway apps compiled with phonegap can play media like audio files? If so, please show me how

Comment: Yes, there is a Media API that lets you play and record media files. Check out the examples under `.play()`: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.play

Comment: Thanks MBillau, I finally figured it out using the phonegap media API

Comment: Welcome! Glad to hear it worked.

Comment: Could you please post an answer on how you did it? Thanks!